# SKAudioNode completion not detected (using SKAction)

Tags: ios, swift, gamekit, skaction, skaudionode

I need to know when an SKAudioNode has finished, but using the SKAction(:completion:) doesn't seem to work:

```
      audioNode.run(SKAction.play()) {

        // do something after it has finished
      }
```

The sound plays fine, but the thing that is supposed to execute on completion actually runs immediately.

Can someone please let me know what I´m doing wrong, and, if possible, how can I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible work-around is to force a delay. Although it works, it´s far from perfect:

```
let sequence = SKAction.sequence( [SKAction.play(), SKAction.wait(forDuration: soundDuration ) ])

audioNode.run(sequence, completion: {
  audioNode.removeFromParent()
})
```

Comment: How do you find out the sound duration?

Comment: Using a tool like Audacity. For my particular case, I can hardcode it.